# Django form fill all models and dynamic template

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I do not find an example for this and I do not know the best way to do it.

The goal is to create one form to fill all models. But, I would like to create a dynamic template. The user can choose in a list something in the database and if he does not find it, he could create the new element in the corresponding model.

Following a picture with an example. The form contains for each model a selection of possibility or a + to add a new possibility to the Model. In this example, Model1 does not have what the user want, so he selects the + and dynamically, the fields' Model1 appear. And so, the user can add the new element.

Thanks for tracks, example of other idea ;)

[image: Design exemple]

Comment: In user perspective it may look like single form, but in back-end you have to create forms specific to models(modelForm) and render all the forms in single context object. In your template you can hide/display based on the '+' buttons.  Again you are using single save button for all forms, because of this you may have to write validators in jquery to avoid errors about non-interested fields. Any specific reason for this design? I It's easy to understand and maintain the app, when it is divided as smaller components. You can come up with different UI where u can deal every form independently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to put 2 forms like you said in one single context(without the + action) but I do not found how to do it properly, nothing is working... And I do not find an example
I have to do this because this is a requierement of my client, and a legitim one (more userfriendly for them)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. Could you please post the code that you have implemented and the challenges that you are facing. Rendering multiple forms is same as rendering single form, only things is you will be creating multiple form objects and including those in context.